# How to hash Double linked list node in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, hash

I am implementing a data structure; a double linked list where items are in range. I want to find whether an item is present or not in O(1). For this, I would like to hash the nodes where the key will be the item & value will be the node.

In Java, there are in built functions to support this kind of feature.

**EDIT:**  In short,i want hashMap kind of thing in C.

What should I do to implement it in C?

Comment: Do you mean hashCode implementation in C? if so - there is nothing similar out-of the box.

Comment: I don't think he means `hashCode()` implementation; I think you're confusing what that function does. I think he means something like Map or HashMap that allow you to put items in a collection and retrieve them in O(1).

Comment: You need to do slightly more research and clarify what you want here. Note you have not provided any example, even in pseudo code, of what you've tried. Also, is this for homework? Implementation of a hashed doubly linked list is a fairly introductory task for learning C.

Comment: @NathanielFord well, if he would state "Structure" - I would agree with you, but he stated "function" - and this is more related to hashCode rather than HashMap.

Comment: @jdevelop Not when he's talking about key-value pairs, but I agree he isn't making himself clear. No sample input/output, or even a discussion of whether he wants O(1) or amortized O(1), for which certain tree structures would be best. Or whether he cares about insertion time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array called "buckets" that contain the key and value, with an optional pointer to create a linked list.

When you access the hash table with a key, you process the key with a custom hash function which will return an integer. You then take the modulus of the result and that is the location of your array index or "bucket". Then you check the unhashed key with the stored key, and if it matches, then you found the right place.

Otherwise, you've had a "collision" and must crawl through the linked list and compare keys until you match. (note some implementations use a binary tree instead of linked list for collisions).

Check out this fast hash table implementation:

http://attractivechaos.awardspace.com/khash.h.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing items in a linked list, also storing them in a hash to do containment testing seems ... suboptimal. Just use the hash table to begin with, and stop using a linked list if you need an operation (O(1) containment testing) that it doesn't support.

Comment: Hash tables don't preserve order.  Adding a linked list to a hash table is fairly common if you care about iteration order.

Comment: I want to implement several other features in list like Enqueue & Dequeue & delete an item in O(1). So, hashing the nodes make sense. But, how can i implement this in C?

Comment: @Aashish By studying data structure theory and practice ... there are many good books on the subject.